# Dropping a permanent Snowflake table without retaining for Fail Safe

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a permanent table which needs to be dropped. Its current retention is set to 1.
This table will no longer be used and will never be required to be restored again.

How do I drop this table without retaining it for Fail Safe?

I am just trying to save on the Fail Safe storage cost. If possible.

Thanks,
T

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to skip fail-safe for permanent tables.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-failsafe.html#what-is-fail-safe

Answer (score 0):

Based on the KB article here:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Change-permanent-table-to-transient-table

There is no way to skip the Fail-Safe as Gokhan mentioned previously.

Just want to share in case it can be useful.